# Why does my ComboBox only show the first result?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I've got a `Combobox`  to which I'm trying to pass arguments from my header row of table.

Issue is, for some reason, my `Combobox` only seems to display the first result, even though it by all logic shouldn't.

> This is my data, ranged from `B2:J2` (issue is it is dynamic, so I
>   cant just pass it via `Properties`
>
> [image]

Upon activation of my `UserForm` I try to fetch the length of the table (as it's dynamic and can change amount of columns prior to `UserForm`activation)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim res As String
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Sheets("Pomocne").Range("B2")
    Dim endcell As Range
    Do Until IsEmpty(cell)
        Set endcell = cell
        Set cell = cell.Offset(0, 1)
    Loop

    res = "Pomocne!B2:" & Replace(endcell.address, "$", "")
    obor_combo.RowSource = res

    Debug.Print res
End Sub
```

Now, everything seems to run fine, as the `Debug.print res` yields the following result:

[image]

which is exactly what I'm passing to `obor_combo.RowSource = res` however. when I check the actual `UserForm` for some unknown reason, it seems to show only the first result.

Any idea what could be the cause?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RowSource` is made for *column-like* range: if you assign it a *row-like* range you'll get the first cell only

But you can use `List` property of `ComboBox` object, and fill it with values obtained transposing the *row-like* range ones:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim res As String
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Sheets("Pomocne").Range("B2")
    Dim endcell As Range
    Do Until IsEmpty(cell)
        Set endcell = cell
        Set cell = cell.Offset(0, 1)
    Loop

    res = "Pomocne!B2:" & Replace(endcell.Address, "$", "")
    obor_combo.List = Application.Transpose(Range(res).Value)    
End Sub
```

which could be simplified to:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()    
    With Sheets("Pomocne")
        obor_combo.List = Application.Transpose(.Range("B2", .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm kind of irked that Microsoft decided to do this system of linking instead of letting users pass a simple `Range` as an argument. EIther way, thanks a lot!

Comment: *Side note*: using the rather unknown **`.Column`** property for comboboxes *(or listboxes)* you can even simplify the assignment to `obor_combo.Column = .Range("B2", .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value` :-) @DisplayName